# Logstash SQLite error "Missing Valuefier handling for full class"

Tags: java, sqlite, ubuntu-14.04, logstash

```
# database
elastic@elastic:~/ELK/database$ sudo sqlite3 data.db
SQLite version 3.8.2 2013-12-06 14:53:30
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> create table test(id integer primary key autoincrement, ip integer, res integer);
sqlite>
sqlite> insert into test (ip,res) values(200,500);
sqlite> insert into test (ip,res) values(300,400);


    # aaa.conf
input{
   sqlite{
     path => "/home/elastic/ELK/database/data.db"
     type => test
   }
}

output{
   stdout{
      codec => rubydebug{}
   }
}




    elastic@elastic:~/ELK/logstash-5.1.1$ sudo bin/logstash -f aaa.conf
Sending Logstash's logs to /home/elastic/ELK/logstash-5.1.1/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2017-04-25T00:11:41,397][INFO ][logstash.inputs.sqlite   ] Registering sqlite input {:database=>"/home/elastic/ELK/database/data.db"}
[2017-04-25T00:11:41,588][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {"id"=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>1, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>5, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>125}
[2017-04-25T00:11:41,589][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline main started
[2017-04-25T00:11:41,632][ERROR][logstash.pipeline        ] A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
  Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::Sqlite path=>"/home/elastic/ELK/database/data.db", type=>"test", id=>"5545bd3bab8541578394a2127848be342094c195-1", enable_metric=>true, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::Plain id=>"plain_1349faf2-3b33-40d0-b328-f588fd97ae7e", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">, batch=>5>
  Error: Missing Valuefier handling for full class name=org.jruby.RubyObject, simple name=RubyObject
```

`Jruby.RubyObject, simple name = RubyObject`. I do not know how to handle that errors.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Did you solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by installing `logstash-input-jdbc` plugin.

I think `jdbc` plugin is requirement of `sqlite` plugin.

So, plugin installation:

```
bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-input-jdbc
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

If you used sqlite plugin 3.0.4 and hit this problem I would say it is probably a bug, I raised it at logstash forum https://discuss.elastic.co/t/sqlite-plugin-3-0-4-failed-to-start-and-it-seems-a-bug/150305

So you can just use jdbc plugin to get your sqlite data, e.g. https://github.com/theangryangel/logstash-output-jdbc/blob/master/examples/sqlite.md

BTW, if you check `logstash-input-sqlite-3.0.4/lib/logstash/inputs/sqlite.rb` it was quite simple actually. But I can't figure out why `event = LogStash::Event.new("host" => @host, "db" => @db)` failed in my case.